# Database model refactoring for combining multiple tables of heterogeneous data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I took over the task of re-developing a database of scientific data which is used by a web interface, where the original author had taken a 'table-per-dataset' approach which didn't scale well and is now fairly difficult to manage with more than 200 tables that have been created. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out how to wrangle the thing, but the datasets contain heterogeneous values, so it is not reasonably possible to combine them into one table with a set schema for column definitions.

I've explored the possibility of EAV, XML columns, and ended up attempting to go with a table with many sparse columns since the database is running on SQL Server 2008. The DBAs are having some issues with my recently created sparse columns causing some havoc with their backup scripts, so I'm left wondering again if there isn't a better way to do this. I know that EAV does not lead to decent performance, and my experiments with XML data types also demonstrated poor performance, probably thanks to the large number of records in some of the tables.

Here's the summary:

- Around 200 tables, most of which have a few columns containing floats and small strings
- Some tables have as many as 15,000 records
- Table schemas are not consistent, as the columns depended on the number of samples in the original experimental data.
- SQL Server 2008

I'll be treating most of this data as legacy in the new version I'm developing, but I still need to be able to display it and query it- and I'd rather not have to do so by dynamically specifying the table name in my stored procedures as it would be with the current multi-table approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: If this is primarily scientific data, are most of the columns numeric? Also, what is a typical number of columns per dataset, and what is the largest number of columns in a dataset?

Comment: What problem are the dba's encountering? Sparse columns shouldn't affect backups, unless they are doing table copies or something.

Comment: Most of the columns are floats, but there are also some short strings here and there. The number of columns per table varies from 1 to 23. Their backup was failing because indexes on sparse columns aren't compressible. They think they dealt with that, and now it's failing for some other reason that they think a service pack will fix, but it's a production server for other things, so avoiding downtime would be nice.

Comment: This seems more like something your DBAs will need to address. Also, floating point numbers are very unpredictable... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the first step is looking to rationalise the data through views; attempt to consolidate similar data sets into logical pools through views.

You could then look at refactoring the code to look at the views, and see if the web platform operates effectively. From there you could decided whether or not the view structure is beneficial and if so, look to physically rationalising the data into a new table.

The benefit of using views in this manner is you should be able to squeak a little performance out of indexes on the views, and it should also give you a better handle on the data (that said, since you are dev'ing the new version, it would suggest you are perfectly capable of understanding the problem domain).

With 200 tables as simple raw data sets, and considering you believe your version will be taking over, I would probably go through the prototype exercise of seeing if you can't write the views to be identically named to what your final table names will be in V2, that way you can also backtest if your new database structure is in fact going to work.

Finally, a word to the wise, when someone has built a database in the way you've described, without looking at the data, and really knowing the problem set; they did it for a reason. Either it was bad design, or there was a cause for what now appears on the surface to be bad design; you raise consistency as an issue - look to wrap the data and see how consistent you can make it.

Good luck!